# Eclipse Java Projects in Git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, projects-and-solutions

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a java project in GIT. In particular I would like to create the git repository such that when I import from git in Eclipse, the project is automatically created correctly with all its .project settings intact and all other settings setup. I.E. if I do a `git clone javaEclipseProject` in my workspace/ folder then do an import on that javaEclipseProject folder it will open up the project without having to use the new project wizard.

Answer (score 5):

Add the dot-files (.project, .classpath and the .settings directory) to the Git repository. That is what we do with the Git plugin itself.

Comment: So create the bare minimum on github first, such as dot files only? Then clone into eclipse, create project folders, packages, java files, etc, then upload to git? Are those the basic steps to follow?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you could do that....but I know even in the company I work for, .project files are not portable from one machine to another. If you get your project building in either Ant or Maven then check it in, Eclipse, Netbeans and/or IntelliJ will be able to check out the project and build their own .project files from your start.

Moving on to the more....shall we say "religious" aspects of the problem, personally I like the way Maven or Ivy or "insert many other Ant++ build tools here" will go ahead and find any dependencies that you might not have already and download them for you. I'm sad to say, but in the times I've used them, Eclipse actually has the least easy to use Maven support though, I don't use IntelliJ, but the snobs.....I mean co-workers I have that do say integration is seamless, and Netbeans it just flawless for Maven.

YMMV of course.

Comment: What plugins create .project files that are not portable between machines? We have the .project files of all our projects in version control and never had any issues.

Comment: I would also like to know that.

Comment: Not plugins, mainly its dependency issues. If the file paths or library paths I have on my system don't match those on yours, I can't just check things out with strictly the base Eclipse config and just hit compile and go. If you're using some open source jar I've never even heard of, and IF you don't also check in all the dependencies, which we don't, why do I need forty thousand copies of log4j in "source" control anyway?? Like I said above, its more about the way you like to work, which I consider a "religious" issue. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create another branch called `eclipse` next to your master branch which stores your additional eclipse project files. To do so, you basically need to:

1. Create a git repository
2. Stage your files, add a `.gitignore` with the content of anything from eclipse for e.g. [this one](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore), commit everything
3. Create a new branch called `eclipse`
4. Alter your `.gitignore` file or clear it, so that it will track your additional files
5. In your project directory execute `git config merge.ours.driver true`
6. Still on your `eclipse` branch, create the file `.gitattributes` and add this line: `.gitignore merge=ours`. This will make git always keep the eclipse's branch version of `.gitignore` when performing a merge.
7. Stage your `.project` file its siblings from eclipse together with your newly created `.gitattributes`
8. After committing all these things your two branches are "in sync" with the difference that your `eclipse` branch additionally contains the project configuration files.

Once you make changes to your source files and commited them to your master branch, you can pull these changes over to your `eclispe` branch by merging it with the `--no-ff` option. It is important that you never do a fast-forward merge into the eclipse branch when using this method! Also never commit changes on your source files to your `eclipse` branch directly, always merge them into - this way you will never get merge conflicts and keep your life simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this existed at the time the question was asked, but eclipse now has a new plugin called **EGit** in which you can import projects from git, commit, push, pull, merge, etc right in eclipse. I just discovered this recently and it's very useful.

If i'm not mistaken, EGit is now built into **Eclipse Mars** without you needing to add it manually. All of the git functions can be found by right clicking on a project and hovering over the **team option**. I use it alot wtih [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

You can find EGit here http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Eclipse Mars is on the home page http://www.eclipse.org/

[image]